# Import collection using button importing same collection multiple times - Postman

Tags: html, postman, postman-collection-runner

I'm using Postman version 6.6.0, and trying import API collection via `Run in Postman` button. I have one HTML page which looks like:

```
<div id="hiddenEnv" class="nodisplay highlight highlight-attention">
   <p>
      Click the button below to import into Postman
   </p>
   <p>                        
   <div class="postman-run-button"
      data-postman-action="collection/import"
      data-postman-var-1="abcd"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      (function (p,o,s,t,m,a,n) {
          !p[s] && (p[s] = function () { (p[t] || (p[t] = [])).push(arguments); });
          !o.getElementById(s+t) && o.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild((
            (n = o.createElement("script")),
            (n.id = s+t), (n.async = 1), (n.src = m), n
          ));
        }(window, document, "_pm", "PostmanRunObject", "https://run.pstmn.io/button.js"));
   </script>        
   </p>
</div>
```

And js code:

```
$(function() {

    var lastEnv;

    function newEnv(name) {
        debugger;
        var env = {
            "id": generateUUID(),
            "name": "MyProject-" + name,
            "values": [{
                    "key": "hostenv",
                    "value": "",
                    "type": "text",
                    "enabled": true
                },
                {
                    "key": "username",
                    "value": "",
                    "type": "text",
                    "enabled": true
                },
                {
                    "key": "password",
                    "value": "",
                    "type": "text",
                    "enabled": true
                }
            ],
            "timestamp": 1544608923,
            "synced": false,
            "syncedFilename": "",
            "team": null,
            "isDeleted": false
        };
        return env;
    }

    $('#enter-creds').on('click', function(ev) {
        var options = {
            "name": "sampleBasicModal",
            "content": $("script#envModal").html(),
            onComplete: function(ev) {
                console.log(ev);
                var modal = $(ev.currentTarget).closest('.modal');
                var form = modal.find('form');
                console.log(form);

                var formArr = form.serializeArray();

                var envName = _.find(formArr, {name: 'hostenv'}).value.split('.')[0];
                var envOutput = newEnv(envName);

                var formObj = {};

                formObj.hostenv = _.find(formArr, {name: 'hostenv'}).value;   
                formObj.username = _.find(formArr, {name: 'username'}).value;
                formObj.password = _.find(formArr, {name: 'password'}).value;     

                if (!_pm('env.create', 'MyProject-' + envName, formObj)) {
                    _pm('env.replace', 'MyProject-' + envName, formObj);
                }

                lastEnv = envOutput;
                $('#shownEnv').remove();
                $('#hiddenEnv').slideDown(750);
            }
        };
        var inst = Olive.modal.show(options);

        ev.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I'm able to import my collections to Postman environment. However, same collection keep adding 7 to 8 times. I couldn't find where is the issue!

**Edit:**
I have checked it few times and then found that issue occurred when I have multiple environments.

Comment: Could you share a deployed version of this?
Or probably something on JSFiddle / codesandbox / a github repo?
I'll be happy to help you out in this

Comment: Thank you @SivcanSingh, sure give me a minute I will share a link of repo

Comment: @SivcanSingh: you can find repo [here](https://github.com/divyang-desai/postman-button-demo)

Comment: I imported it but it only imports the collection once (latest version of the app). Not 4-5 times or more. Can you share more information about the OS?
Unable to reproduce this. Can you try out using the Postman Canary build (download - https://www.getpostman.com/canary)? 

Just open Postman Canary and then click Run in Postman and see if it's happening again?

Comment: I see this issue with my work station system(OS: win10), however not able to reproduce with home system, there would be some issue, I will update with my question tomorrow with screens

Comment: Oh sure, let me know. :)

Comment: @SivcanSingh, I have checked it few times and then found that issue occurred when I have multiple environments, question updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185182/discussion-between-sivcan-singh-and-div).

Comment: @SivcanSingh, anyway help on [Pre request script of upload file with multipart/form-data hitting method 2 times in Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53886758/4753489)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing this issue with a Postman team member, they found that there is an issue in the Postman with Windows OS, here is the reported link

[Collection getting imported multiple times when using RiP button [Windows]](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/5639)